# show that $f_n \xrightarrow{w^*} 0$ in $l^\infty$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

let $f_n$ be sequence of unit vectors in $l^p,1\leq p\leq \infty$.

then show that $f_n \xrightarrow{w^*} 0$ in $l^\infty$.

i know that if $X$  is any normed  space , and $f_n ,f\in X^*$ then $f_n\xrightarrow{w^*} f$ if $f_n(x)\to f(x) \forall x\ \in X$ .

and i also know $(l^1)^*=l^{\infty}$. it mean for every $f\in (l^1)^*$ there exist sequence $a_n \in l^{\infty}$ such that $$f(x)=\sum _{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_i a_i$$ where $(\alpha_i)$ is coordinates of $x$ with respect to basis $(e_i)$. also $||f||=||a_n||_{\infty}$

now how to use this in this problem. any hint

thanks in advanced

Comment: What do you mean by "let $f_n$ be sequence of unit vectors", exactly? In particular do you mean _a_ sequence of unit vectors, or do you have some specific sequence  in mind? It's certainly not true that $f_n\to0$ for every sequence of unit vectors...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich nothing more is given in problem. it simply say $f_n$ is sequence of unit vectors.may be it is standred  sequence $e_n$

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that is says "$f_n$ is sequence of unit vectors". That's atrocious English, and here it makes a big difference. Does it say _a_ sequence of unit vectors or _the_ sequence of unit vectors?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich it say let $f_n$ be a sequence of unit vectors in $l^p$

Comment: Ok. In that case the exercise is simply wrong. Counterexample: Let $f_1$ be any unit vector, and let $f_n=f_1$ for every $n$.